# Will launching a copied paid Market Place AMI incur developer costs?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Say I grab a developer made AMI in the AWS marketplace, then I make a copy of it as my own AMI, will I still pay the developer hourly fees to run the copied AMI?

I know that you can copy the AMIs by launching the developer AMI and then making your own AMI from the launched instance. So would deleting the developer instance and then launching one from your personal copy incur the same costs?

I can't find any documentation on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you launch from marketplace, create an image and re-launch from that new image then **yes** it will still be recognised as the marketplace product.

There are convoluted ways to create an image without a link to the original marketplace product but it’s borderline with software piracy so I won’t go into the details here.